# VS Code / Sublime Text 3 Operators as Symbols

Tags: sublimetext3, visual-studio-code, sublime-text-plugin

I once saw VS Code in a video where it converted **PHP** `object` and `arrow` operators from:

`->` to →

and

`=>` to ⇒

I could no longer find the video and I've exhausted all possible terms I know of in search whether it's a built-in feature or an extension, or whatnot.

1. If it's a config, how do I do it?
2. If it's an extension, where do I find it?
3. Can I configure Sublime with it?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: As I know the `fonts with ligatures` is what you need to google.

Comment: And then just download the font, install it on system and choose as main font in VSCode settings.

Comment: Thank you @Vadim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ligatures**, yes. Would have never crossed my mind.
Thanks Vadim.

FiraCode:
https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode